# Bonferroni in ANOVA

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Hi I am trying to use ANOVA to compare between the groups. I came across an article "[bonferroni](https://www.statology.org/bonferroni-correction-in-r/)" which explains a method to do a Bonferroni test in R. However, I am unable to find a function such as `pairwise` in Mathematica.
To reproduce the same example in the [link](https://www.statology.org/bonferroni-correction-in-r/) I have tried this so far:

```
Needs["ANOVA`"]
trialList= {76, 77, 77, 81, 82, 82, 83, 84, 85, 89, 81, 82, 83, 83, 83, 84, 87, 90, 92, 93, 77, 78, 79, 88, 89, 90, 91, 95, 95, 98}
indices=ConstantArray[{1, 2, 3}, 10] // Transpose // Flatten
       (*{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}*)
ANOVA[{indices, trialList} // Transpose, PostTests -> Bonferroni,  CellMeans -> False]
```

This gives me the anova table, but I can't find a way to find the Bonferroni as explained in the 4th step of [bonferreni](https://www.statology.org/bonferroni-correction-in-r/). I would appreciate any help or workaround. Thank you.

Comment: Jenny Baglivo's book *Mathematica Laboratories for Mathematical Statistics: Emphasizing Simulation and Computer Intensive Methods* [https://amzn.to/3Sk8bGo] has an implementation of Bonferroni; the code can be downloaded from her website [https://jennybaglivo.bc.edu/curriculum/mathematical-statistics/] (the Bonferroni stuff is in the `Group4.m` file)

Comment: I'm not sure what you think is missing.  With the code you used you get as part of the output `PostTests->{Model->Bonferroni {1,3}}` which tells you that using the Bonferroni adjustment the means of index 1 and index 3 are significantly different at the 0.05 level (and neither of the other 2 pairwise comparisons are significantly different).  That's all you're going to get from `ANOVA`.  If you want more, you'll need to go the *R* route or use `LinearModelFit`.  But in any event you need to spell out exactly what kind of output you need.

Comment: @JimB Thanks Jim, the thing that's missing is the relative p values based on which Bonferroni has pointed out {1,3}. I have used `PairedTtest` but the pvalues differ because they're not relative to the next pair. The type of output I need is provided in the link in the question.

Comment: Your data doesn't appear to be paired so I wouldn't use the `PairedTtest`.  If the 10 sets of `{1, 2, 3}` values are blocks, then that would justify using the `PairedTtest` but it invalidates your current use of `ANOVA` that appears to ignore that blocking.

Comment: @JimB, sorry, my bad, this is just a sample from the example in the link. For my research, I study the lists as a pair like lists {1,2,3} are the individual plans, and we can always compare the plans forming a pair like {1,2} or {2,3}. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

Also, there is a workaround way of getting the results. But, you need to use a dependency [RLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/guide/RLink.html) Package. Essentially do it in R.

```
<< RLink`
InstallR[]


RSet["vec1", trialList];
RSet["Index", indices];

dff = REvaluate["{ds<-data.frame(idx=Index, dose=vec1); head(ds);
model <- aov(dose~ idx, data = ds);
summary(model);
vals<-pairwise.t.test(ds$dose, ds$idx, p.adjust.method=\"bonferroni\");
 }"][[1, 3]]
DeleteMissing /@ (fromRObject[dff] // Quiet)
(*{{0.308928}, {0.0478164, 1.}}*)
```